# Laravel command run 2 days per week

Tags: laravel

This has been asked a few times before, and all the answers are 'try this `->cron(...)`' which I know will work, but I'd love to write this fluently as it's much more readable.

The question is if this works:

```
$schedule->command('command')->mondays()->thursdays()->dailyAt(6);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if this didn't work:

```
$schedule->command('command')->mondays()->thursdays()->dailyAt(6);
```

You can take a look of the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling#scheduling-artisan-commands)
And use the function `days` that get in parameters an array of days *(Sundays=0, mondays=1, thursdays=4)* :

```
$schedule->command('command')->weekly()->days([1,4])->at('6:00');
```

May it helps you

Comment: I actually don't know if what I proposed works, it's difficult to test :-). But I missed this in the docs, thanks!